# "Error retrieving information from server RPC S-7 AEC-0" while testing Google in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing

I am trying to implement Google in app billing to my Application. I created SKU product id and implemented the billing process in code. While I am trying to test the in-app billind after I enter all the test account details, location, phone no etc and clicking save button it gives the error `"Error retrieving information from server RPC S-7 AEC-0"`. I too published the app created the test account and signed in to the device with test account.

Can any one please help me to fix this. I am totally messed up....

Comment: check my answer below.I have solved the problem after removing all older classes by replacing new ones and main activity code also.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem while implementing the in app billing version 3 into my project. It is very awkward issue.we have tried to resolve it and tried to find out the solution but we can not found any solution to resolve it, searched on Google or Stack Over Flow and many other sites but no luck.Have try to remove account account from the phone and clear cache of play store but not getting success.

I think this is fault on previous sample code and that is solved in the new sample code.

**what you should do to get solution?**

I believe you just have to get the updated code the the in-app billing classes and you shouldn't run into the same problem again.

Google hasn't pushed out the changes to the SDK Manager yet as far as I know. Just copy/paste the new classes into yours and you shouldn't run into the problem any longer.

and also remove your code of purchase product activity(MainActivity in the sample code).

Get the new code changes here:

https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/detail?r=7ec85a9b619fc5f85023bc8125e7e6b1ab4dd69f&path=/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/MainActivity.java

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Sniper let me know it will help you or not.

Answer (score 0):

If other ways didn't help, try to make sure that no apps have made any changes to your system settings, for example, disabling the permissions of google play services, something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that only cards with a US billing address can be added on the Wallet app.

Go to Settings and tap Credit and debit cards.
Tap the + sign, on the top-right corner, and enter your card's information. If you see a camera icon in the "Card number" field, you can take a picture of your card's number instead of entering it manually.
Tap Add credit or debit card.
Reference:
https://support.google.com/wallet/troubleshooter/3222463?hl=en&ref_topic=3209985#ts=2896139,2896157